# Missing title bar after adding Default-568h@2x.png for iPhone 5 support

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios6, iphone-5

I created a new solution with Monotouch 6.0.2 of type MonoTouch/Universal/Master-Detail. I wrote no single line of my own code. When I start the app, all looks great.
Then I add an image of 640x1136 pixel to support the iPhone 5 named Default-568h@2x.png to the solution (type content). When I start the solution again (after a rebuild), the title bar is gone and there is no toolbar at the bottom of the screen. No navigation is possible. Please look at the attached image (left side ok, right side no really).
What's wrong here?

Thanks,
Jan

[image]

Comment: Don't know anything about monotouch but this looks like it could be an autolayout problem.

Comment: I agree with endy, try adding a title and a button to the tab bar.  Perhaps they've hidden because there isn't anything to show

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
I had this problem with my "real" app which has a title and also buttons in it. It has a toolbar, too.
This app has exactly the same problem. Because I was not able to figure out what the cause of the problem is, I tried it with a completely new solution without any code of my own. 
By the way: I can click on details in the demo app. The details controller will be shown, but there is no Back button in the title bar (because there is no title bar visible).
I cannot imagine that I am the only one with that problem. Or is my machine totally misconfigured....